# class jenkins.model.Jenkins$21 cannot access its superclass hudson.model.FullDuplexHttpChannel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am using jenkins.model.Jenkins in my project for which I am grabbing hudson-core jar.

compile group: 'org.jvnet.hudson.main', name: 'hudson-core', version: '2.2.1'

My project builds succesfully but when I use its jar in other project, I get following error.

> class jenkins.model.Jenkins$21 cannot access its superclass hudson.model.FullDuplexHttpChannel

Any kind of suggestion for resolution is appreciated.

Comment: Are you building a plugin for Jenkins or Hudson? Are you following the Jenkins tutorial if its Jenkins? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

Comment: We have a customized release plugin. I am making some modifications.